# new object issue

Tags: android

I'm new to Android Studio.

I made a TextView and a Button in Android Studio.

when I click button it supposed to trigger this method:

```
 public void click (View view)
   {
   TextView tex = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);
   tex.setText("Hello");
   }
```

The code works in this way .
but when I made the method like this:

```
public void click (View view)
       {
       TextView tex = new TextView(this);
       findViewById(R.id.text_view);
       tex.setText("Hello");
       }
```

the code doesn't do what it supposed to do. I mean nothing happen to the TextView text.

Can anyone explain to me what's the difference? and why this happens or what's wrong about the second case?

Comment: in second line you find text view by its ID but there no assignment... the issue is connecting text view to element that you find in container. obvious and simple.

Comment: Instead of those 3 lines, Simply you can also use `findViewById(R.id.text_view).setText("Your Text");` but this way is used when the widget is only used once and that's why no need to create an object for it.

Answer (score 0):

`TextView tex = new TextView(this);`
That code creates new textview instance but this textview has no connection with your view.

But     `TextView tex = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);` finds the first descendant view with the given ID and assigns it to your local variable so you have connection.

More info https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#findViewById(int)

Answer (score 0):

```
public void click (View view)
   {
   TextView tex = new TextView(this);
   findViewById(R.id.text_view);
   tex.setText("Hello");
   }
```

In this section, tex is a textView object but it does not have any field on the view.

```
TextView tex= findViewById(R.id.textView)
```

this line assigns a view to tex object.
The reason is quite obvious.

Answer (score 0):

it seems to me that you are fairly new to programming and doesn't understand java very well, and doesn't have any programming experience of some sort. You see, Semi colons are used to terminate a line of code. So, thats one of the things you missed. Second, this:

```
TextView tex = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);
tex.setText("Hello");
```

gets a reference from a view on the first line and sets the text on the second line. While this:

```
TextView tex = new TextView(this);
findViewById(R.id.text_view);
tex.setText("Hello");
```

Creates a new view on the first line. Gets a reference of the view on the second whilst not using its reference. And sets the text on the third line to the new view that was created on the first line.

## Suggestion

OOP is not a really hard subject, but, if you really want to code, better know a little more about simple programming before diving in to OOP.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById(int)

findviewbyid returns a View.

```
TextView tex = new TextView(this);
findViewById(R.id.text_view);
```

when you do this, you created a new TextView but you never actualy did anything with the View returned by findViewById since you ignored it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two good ways to this as listed below

1. setOnClickListner
2. Using android view binding library (Maybe in combination with ViewModel and difficult, research nice and slow ! :p)
3. using `android:onClick="methodName()"` attribute, (I personally don't prefer this, AFAIK doesn't work in fragment)

Here is the Easiest one!
Put this code into `onCreate` after `setContentView` is called

```
Button btn = findViewById(R.id.your_btn_id);
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //handle triggner here i.e set hello to your textView
            }
        });
```

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You need add tex into your layout to see it:

```
((ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.some_container_id)).addView(tex)
```

When you call

```
findViewById(R.id.text_view);
```

and ignore returning value, this function have no effect